# How to "undo" feature scaling/normalization for output?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

I'm normalizing (or standardizing or feature scaling) my neural network training inputs and training targets.  I just doing linear scaling and the formula I'm using is:

`I = Imin + (Imax-Imin)*(D-Dmin)/(Dmax-Dmin)`

where `I` is the scaled input value, `Imin` and `Imax` are the desired min and max range of the scaled values, `D` is the original data value, and `Dmin` and `Dmax` are the min and max range of the original data values.  In my case I'm setting `Imax` to 1 and `Imin` to -1.

I'm trying to predict a continuous real-valued output.  How do I scale the output of my network back into the "unscaled" range?

Comment: **Hint**: If $y = a + b(x-c)$, and you know $y,a,b$, and $c$, can you solve for $x$?

Comment: @cardinal: I see your point, I guess it's easy.  Although I guess this also means I need to store the original Dmax and Dmin somewhere.  Also in general looking for guidance with respect to interpreting output of neural network back into real-world problem space.

Comment: I think you got the gist of it. In general, neural network is considered as a blackbox (or magicbox) to predict future values. So you can use common sense to interpret its output but there is no way to interpret the model itself.