# Multiple regression - how to calculate the predicted value after feature normalization?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, multidimensional-scaling

I'm currently doing the Andrew Ng machine learning course on coursera, and in Week2 he discusses feature scaling.

I have seen the lecture and read many posts; I understand the reasoning behind feature scaling (basically to make gradient descent converge faster by representing all the features on roughly the same scale).

My problem arises when I try to do it. I'm using Octave, and I have the the code for gradient descent with linear regression set up: it computes the 'theta' matrix for the hypothesis just fine for non-scaled values, giving accurate predictions.

When I use scaled values of input matrix X and output vector Y, the values of theta and the cost function J(theta) calculated are different than from the un-scaled values. Is this normal? How do I 'undo' the scaling, so that when I test my hypothesis with real data, I get accurate results?

For reference, here is the scaling function I am using (in Octave):

```
function [scaledX, avgX, stdX] = feature_scale(X)
    is_first_column_ones=0; %a flag indicating if the first column is ones
    sum(X==1)
    if sum(X==1)(1) == size(X)(1)   %if the first column is ones
        is_first_column_ones=1;
        X=X(:,2:size(X)(2));    %strip away the first column;
    end

    stdX=std(X);
    avgX=mean(X);

    scaledX=(X-avgX)./stdX;

    if is_first_column_ones
        %add back the first column of ones; they require no scaling.
        scaledX=[ones(size(X)(1),1),scaledX];
    end
end
```

Do I scale my test input, scale my theta, or both?

I should also note that I'm scaling as such:

```
scaledX=feature_scale(X);
scaledY=feature_scale(Y);
```

where X and Y are my input and output respectively. Each column of X represents a different feature (the first column is always 1 for the bias feature theta0) and each row of X represents a different input example. Y is a 1-D column matrix where each row is an output example, corresponding to the input of X.

eg: X = [1, x, x^2]

```
 1.00000    18.78152   352.74566
 1.00000     0.61030     0.37246
 1.00000    21.41895   458.77124
 1.00000     3.83865    14.73521
```

Y =

```
99.8043
 1.8283
168.9060
-29.0058
```

^ this is for the function y=x^2 - 14x + 10

Comment: Multivariate regression is not a synonym of multiple regression: multivariate flags several responses.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to stats (I'm coming from a programming background) and I thought they were synonymous.

Comment: Is the theta values obtained from gradient descent equal to as they obtained from normal equation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should perform feature normalization only on features - so only on your input vector $x$. Not on output $y$ or $\theta$. When you trained a model using feature normalization, then you should apply that normalization every time you make a prediction. Also it is expected that you have different $\theta$ and cost function $J(\theta)$ with and without normalization. There is no need to ever undo feature scaling.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I've made a few changes to the code based on @Yurii's answer.

Okay it seems that after a little fiddling about and checking out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/how-to-undo-feature-scaling-normalization-for-output) answer, I got it to work:

As mentioned, I used

[scaledX,avgX,stdX]=feature_scale(X)

to scale the features. I then used gradient descent to get the vector theta, which is used to make predictions.

Concretely, I had:

```
>> Y   % y=(a^2 -14*a + 10) as the equation of my data
Y = 
-38.4218
-31.8576
 74.2568
 38.2865
-10.7453
 36.6208
-35.3849
-9.2554
 137.4463
 3.0049

>> X  %[ 1, a, a^2 ] as my features
X = 
 1.00000     6.23961    38.93277
 1.00000     4.32748    18.72707
 1.00000    17.64222   311.24782
 1.00000     7.84469    61.53913
 1.00000     1.68448     2.83749
 1.00000     5.45754    29.78479
 1.00000     5.09865    25.99620
 1.00000     1.54614     2.39056
 1.00000    20.28331   411.41264
 1.00000     0.51888     0.26924


>> [scaledX, avgX, stdX]=feature_scale(X)

scaledX =
   1.00000  -0.12307  -0.35196
   1.00000  -0.40844  -0.49038
   1.00000   1.57863   1.51342
   1.00000   0.11646  -0.19711
   1.00000  -0.80287  -0.59922
   1.00000  -0.23979  -0.41463
   1.00000  -0.29335  -0.44058
   1.00000  -0.82352  -0.60228
   1.00000   1.97278   2.19956
   1.00000  -0.97683  -0.61681

avgX =
    7.0643   90.3138

stdX =
     6.7007   145.9833


>> %No need to scale Y

>> [theta,costs_vector]=LinearRegression_GradientDescent(scaledX, Y, alpha=1, number_of_iterations=2000);

FINAL THETA:
theta =
  -16.390
  -70.020
   75.617


FINAL COST: 3.41577e-28
```

Now, the model has been trained.

When I did not use feature scaling, the theta matrix would come to approximately: theta=[10, -14, 1], which reflected the function y=x^2 -14x + 10 which we are trying to predict.

With feature scaling, as you can see, the theta matrix is completely different. However, we still use it to make predictions, as follows:

```
>> test_input = 15;
>> testX=[1, test_input, test_input^2]
testX =
     1    15   225
>> scaledTestX=testX;
>> scaledTestX(2)=(scaledTestX(2)-avgX(1))/stdX(1);
>> scaledTestX(3)=(scaledTestX(3)-avgX(2))/stdX(2);
>> scaledTestX
scaledTestX =
   1.00000   1.18431   0.92261
>>
>> final_predicted=(theta')*(scaledTestX')
scaledPredicted =  25.000
>> % 25 is the correct value:
>> % f(a)=a^2-14a+10, at a=15 (our input value) is 25
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand the concepts explained in the previous 2 answers i.e. after we do feature scaling and calculate the intercept (θ<sub>0</sub>) and the slope (θ<sub>1</sub>), we get a hypothesis function (`h(x)`) which uses the scaled down features (Assuming univariate/single variable linear regression)

> h(x) = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>x' -- (1)

where

> x' = (x-μ)/σ -- (2)

(μ = mean of the feature set x; σ = standard deviation of feature set x)

As Yurii said above, we don't scale the  target i.e. `y` when doing feature scaling. So to predict `y` for some x<sub>m</sub>, we simply scale the new input value and feed it into the new hypothesis function (1) using (2)

> x'<sub>m</sub> = (x<sub>m</sub>-μ)/σ -- (3)

And use this in (1) to get the estimated `y`. And I think this should work perfectly fine in practice.

But I wanted to plot the regression line against the original i.e. unscaled features and target values. So I needed a way to scale it back. Coordinate geometry to the rescue! :)

Equation (1) gives us the hypothesis with the scaled feature `x'`. And we know (2) is the relation between the scaled feature `x'` and the original feature `x`. So we substitute (2) in (1) and we get (after simplification):

> h(x) = (θ<sub>0</sub> - θ<sub>1</sub>*μ/σ) + (θ<sub>1</sub>/σ)x -- (4)

So to plot a line with the original i.e. unscaled features, we just use the intercept as (θ<sub>0</sub> - θ<sub>1</sub>*μ/σ) and the slope as (θ<sub>1</sub>/σ).

Here is my complete R code which does the same and plots the regression line:

```
if(exists("dev")) {dev.off()} # Close the plot

rm(list=c("f", "X", "Y", "m", "alpha", "theta0", "theta1", "i")) # clear variables

f<-read.csv("slr12.csv") # read in source data (data from here: http://goo.gl/fuOV8m)

mu<-mean(f$X) # mean

sig<-sd(f$X) # standard deviation

X<-(f$X-mu)/sig # feature scaled

Y<-f$Y # No scaling of target
m<-length(X)

alpha<-0.05

theta0<-0.5

theta1<-0.5

for(i in 1:350) {
    theta0<-theta0 - alpha/m*sum(theta0+theta1*X-Y)
    theta1<-theta1 - alpha/m*sum((theta0+theta1*X-Y)*X)
    print(c(theta0, theta1))
}
plot(f$X,f$Y) # Plot original data
theta0p<-(theta0-theta1*mu/sig) # "Unscale" the intercept
theta1p<-theta1/sig # "Unscale" the slope
abline(theta0p, theta1p, col="green") # Plot regression line
```

You can test that `theta0p` and `theta1p` are correct above by running `lm(f$Y~f$X)` to use the inbuilt linear regression function. The values are the same!

```
> print(c(theta0p, theta1p))
[1] 867.6042128   0.3731579
> lm(f$Y~f$X)

Call:
lm(formula = f$Y ~ f$X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          f$X  
   867.6042       0.3732
```

[image]