# Denormalize Predicted Values

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

How to transform (d e normalize) predicted values when I normalize the data in the range between -1 to 1?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/how-to-undo-feature-scaling-normalization-for-output) for the [-1,1] case.

Comment: I think the answer on the linked post to the [0,1] case is not especially enlightening for the [-1,1] case (there's not much by way of algebraic explanation there). I think it would be justifiable to keep this thread open, albeit as a near-duplicate. Denormalising data that's been scaled to [-1,1] is a task common enough not to expect people to read through an answer to the [0,1] case and have to do the remaining working themselves, in my opinion.

Comment: This may not (or may) be a duplicate, but really does need more elaboration to be answerable, IMO.